# near-example/workshop--exploring-assemblyscript-contracts/assembly/A.sample-projects/04.token-contract/

Tags: blockchain, documentation, smartcontracts, nearprotocol, assemblyscript

I was reading the 04.token-contract(https://github.com/near-examples/workshop--exploring-assemblyscript-contracts/blob/master/assembly/A.sample-projects/04.token-contract/assembly/index.ts).

What's the concept difference between the exported functions:

`export function transfer(to: string, tokens: u64): boolean`

and

`export function transferFrom(from: string, to: string, tokens: u64): boolean` ?

**And please, would it be okay to include a little documentation for this smart contract?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Both functions are implementing the interface defined in the [ERC-20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md) token standard.

`transfer()` is used for spending your own tokens.

If someone else has approved you (by executing the `approve()` function) to spend some of their tokens, you can use the `transferFrom()` function, pass their address as the `from` param, and spend tokens from their address (up to the approved amount).